# How to determine if a table contains a value in SQL?

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, jdbc, ms-access-2013

I feel like I'm missing something very obvious here, but it seems that the only way to go about doing this is to get the value, and then see if it returns a null (empty) value, which I would rather not do.

Is there an equivalent to List.contains(Object o) in SQL? Or perhaps the JDBC has something of that nature? If so, what is it?

I am using Microsoft Access 2013.

Unfortunately I don't have any useful code to show, but here is the gist of what I am trying to do. It isn't anything unique at all. I want to have a method (Java) that returns the values of a user that are stored in the database. If the user has not previously been added to the database, the user should be added, and the default values of the user should be set. Then those newly created values will be returned. If a player has already been added to the database (with the username as the primary key), I don't want to overwrite the data that is already there.

---

I would also advise against using MS Access for this purpose, but if you are familiar with MS Office applications, the familiar UI/UX structure might help you get your footing and require less time to learn other database environments. However, MS Access tends to be quite limited, and I would advise considering alternative options if available.

Comment: What is wrong with `SELECT 1 FROM <table> WHERE <column> = <value> LIMIT 1;`?

Comment: I suppose nothing is wrong with it. I'm very new to SQL, and I'm used to those type of things having pre-existing functions that take care of that operation, such as List.contains(Object o). I can always just make my own method in Java that does that operation for me. I just always like to limit repetitive code as much as I can, and I would be using that a lot.

Comment: Can you describe what you want the code to do?  Say you have a query, what should the query return?

Comment: I am new to SQL, and it's not like what I am trying to do is unique. If someone who has never used my application before tries to use the database, they should just be added, with their username being the primary key. If they have already been added, the code shouldn't attempt to add them to the database again.

Comment: In JDBC, you should _definitely_ use a `PreparedStatement` with static SQL rather than evaluating something with a string that comes from a user. Otherwise you may let in the demons of sql-injection…

Answer (score 6):

The only way to see if an SQL table contains a row with some condition on a column is to actually make an SQL query. I don't see why you wouldn't do that. Just make sure that you have an index on the column that you will be constraining the results on. Also for better speed use `count` to prevent from retrieving all the data from the rows.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM foos WHERE bar = 'baz'
```

Assuming you have an index on the `bar` column this query should be pretty fast and all you have to do is check whether it returns > 0. If it does then you have rows matching your criteria.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "`IF EXISTS`" which returns a `boolean` value of `1` or `0`.

```
select
  if(
    exists( select * from date1 where current_date()>now() ),
    'today > now',
    'today is not > now' 
  ) as 'today > now ?' ;

+--------------------+
| today > now?       |
+--------------------+
| today is not > now |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

***Another Example***:

```
SELECT IF( 
         EXISTS( SELECT col from tbl where id='n' ),
         colX, colY 
       ) AS 'result'
FROM TBL;
```

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but how would I go about doing this using the JDBC?

Comment: @TacoManStan: Check my *Another Example*.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also new to sql and I'm using Oracle.

In Oracle, suppose we have: TYPE: value.

We can use:

```
where value not in (select TYPE from table)
```

to make sure *value* not exist in the column TYPE of the table.

Don't know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use  Query with condition.

For example if you have to check records with particular coloumn, you can use `where` condition

```
select * from table where column1 = 'checkvalue'
```

You can use `count` property to check the no. of records existing with your specified conditon

```
select count(*) from table where column1 = 'checkvalue'
```

Answer (score -2):

I have created the following method, which to my knowledge works perfectly. (Using the java.sql package)

```
public static containsUser(String username)
{
    //connection is the Connection object used to connect to my Access database.
    Statement statement = this.connection.createStatement();
    //"Users" is the name of the table, "Username" is the primary key.
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = '" + username + "'";
    Result result = statement.executeQuery(sql);
    //There is no need for a loop because the primary key is unique.
    return result.next();
}
```

It's an extremely simple and extremely basic method, but hopefully it might help someone in the future.
If there is anything wrong with it, please let me know. I don't want anyone learning from or using poorly written code.

IMPORTANT EDIT: It is now over half a decade after I wrote the above content (both question and answer), and I now advise *against* the solution I illustrated above.

While it does work, it prioritizes a "Java-mindset-friendly" approach to SQL. In short, it is typically a bad idea to migrate paradigms and mindsets of one language to another, as it is inevitable that you will eventually find yourself trying to fit a square peg into a round hole. The only way to make that work is to shave the corners off the square. The peg will then of course fit, but as you can imagine, starting with a circle peg in the first place would have been the better, cleaner, and less messy solution.

Instead, refer to the above upvoted answers for a more realistic, enterprise-friendly solution to this problem, especially as I imagine the people reading this are likely in a similar situation as I was when I originally wrote this.

Comment: I dont get your return. Specially, I don't get your method's signature with no return type.

Comment: why would u select * into memory just to see if something exists